# Infinite Loop using React, Redux and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I have a collection of profile documents in firebase and I want to render them in the profiles page, however after I have updated the userProfiles state and use useDispatch to store the state in the slice, I get an infinite loop when rendering the profile page.

I have tried putting the dispatch() into a useEffect, not in a useEffect and inside the querySnapshot promise but I'm still getting an infinite loop wherever I put it.

Any feedback is appreciated, thank you.

```
\\ profiles.js

export const Profiles = () => {
  const [userProfiles, setUserProfiles] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  db.collection("customers")
    .doc(user.info.uid)
    .collection("profiles")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setUserProfiles(documents);
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(profiles(userProfiles));
  }, []);

  console.log({ userProfiles });

  return (
    <div className="profile_container">
      <h1 className="profile_title">Who's Watching?</h1>
      <div className="profile_row">
        {userProfiles.map((profile) => {
          return (
            <div className="profile_individualProfile">
              <img
                src="https://occ-0-300-1167.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/K6hjPJd6cR6FpVELC5Pd6ovHRSk/AAAABY5cwIbM7shRfcXmfQg98cqMqiZZ8sReZnj4y_keCAHeXmG_SoqLD8SXYistPtesdqIjcsGE-tHO8RR92n7NyxZpqcFS80YfbRFz.png?r=229"
                alt="profile"
              />
              <p>{profile.name}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div
          onClick={() => navigate("/add-profile")}
          className="profile_addProfile_container"
        >
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/FFFFFF/plus--v1.png"
            alt="add profile"
          />
          <h2>Add Profile</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
\\ userSlice.js

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: {
      info: null,
      profiles: [],
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user.info = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user.info = null;
    },
    profiles: (state, action) => {
      state.user.profiles.push(action.payload);
      },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current implementation, when your page is rendered, `db.collections` runs and you set state `setUserProfiles(documents)` which renders your app and again `db.collections` runs. to prevent this you should run `db.collections` in `useEffect`.

```
// fetch users only when your app renders
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("customers")
      .doc(user.info.uid)
      .collection("profiles")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        setUserProfiles(documents);
      });
  }, []);
```

have another useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(profiles(userProfiles));
  }, [userProfiles]);
```

this will NOT work neither. `setUserProfiles` will be causing issue. Because when app renders, you fetch data, you set the state, change the `userProfiles`, this will rerender app again.

The problem with your code is you do not need `setUserProfiles`. instead in `db.collections()` when you get the documents, you dispatch the documents and then access the profiles from redux with `useSelector`

```
// fetch users only when your app renders
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("customers")
      .doc(user.info.uid)
      .collection("profiles")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        // setUserProfiles(documents); You do not need this
        dispatch(profiles(userProfiles))
      });
  }, []);
```

Now use `useSelector` to reach the state in `redux`

```
// assuming reducers name is "users"
  const usersState = useSelector((state) => state.users);
```

now when you use map guard your app

```
 // make sure you use the correct data
 // you migh need to destructure
 {usersState && usersState.map((profile) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into this issue you may find this useful. Following from yilmaz's helpful answer, I had to update the Profiles.js and userSlice.js as follows...

```
// Profiles.js

export const Profiles = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const usersState = useSelector(profiles);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("customers")
      .doc(usersState.payload.user.user.info.uid)
      .collection("profiles")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        !usersState.payload.user.user.profiles.includes((arr) =>
          documents.every(arr)
        ) && dispatch(profiles(documents));
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="profile_container">
      <h1 className="profile_title">Who's Watching?</h1>
      <div className="profile_row">
        {usersState.payload.user.user.profiles.map((profile) => {
          console.log(profile);

          return (
            <div className="profile_individualProfile">
              <img
                src="https://occ-0-300-1167.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/K6hjPJd6cR6FpVELC5Pd6ovHRSk/AAAABY5cwIbM7shRfcXmfQg98cqMqiZZ8sReZnj4y_keCAHeXmG_SoqLD8SXYistPtesdqIjcsGE-tHO8RR92n7NyxZpqcFS80YfbRFz.png?r=229"
                alt="profile"
              />
              <p>{profile.name}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div
          onClick={() => navigate("/add-profile")}
          className="profile_addProfile_container"
        >
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/FFFFFF/plus--v1.png"
            alt="add profile"
          />
          <h2>Add Profile</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
// userSlice.js

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: {
      info: null,
      profiles: [],
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user.info = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user.info = null;
    },
    profiles: (state, action) => {
      state.user.profiles.length = 0;

      state.user.profiles.push(...action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```